# Why does 50/60hz waveform sometimes appear to change direction when imaged on an oscilloscope?

Tags: electric-current, frequency

http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-32898-stock-footage-an-old-oscilloscope-demonstrates-a-waveform.html

The video above displays a waveform moving from left to right. This is generally how my oscilloscope behaves, however in some instances a 50hz ac waveform changes direction? Can anyone offer an explanation as to why and how this happens?

Comment: I thought that might be the reason, however I can turn the trigger off and observe the waveform changing direction without out any modifications to the scope. How would you explain that?

Comment: @CuriousOne Please convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your oscilloscope is not triggering on the signal, the horizontal deflection time is set near a multiple of the period of the 50/60Hz wave and the instruments starts at slightly later phase each time it traces the waveform. That way the wave seems to move "backward" in time. If it starts tracing at a slightly earlier phase, then the wave seems like it's moving "forward". In reality, of course, it's just a stroboscopic effect.

Additionally, the horizontal deflection time circuits in most instruments are not very stable (they don't have to be because a scope is usually used in trigger mode, so timing is reset every cycle), so the deflection frequency shifts around. If you do the same experiment with a digital DAQ system with a sampling clock that is derived from a crystal oscillator, the phase shift will only go one way or the wave will be standing virtually still if, by chance, the sampling frequency is an integer multiple of the 50 or 60Hz signal.